# how to exit a for loop when variable doesn't change anymore in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

if in a for loop, I have a variable, it doesn't change for 30 times, I will stop the loop.

```
for i in range(100):
    if b > a:
      c= 0
    if b < a:
      c = 1
```

If c stays at 0 continually for more than 30 times,then I will stop it. 
How to write code for this part?

I am thinking using list to record them, if sum(i for i in c[-30:]) is 0.

Is there any other decent way to express this?
Thank you~

Comment: keep a count, break if `count > 30`?

Answer (score 2):

Simple thing to do will be, to put another if statement inside the loop

```
j = 0
for i in range(100):
  if b > a:
    c= 0
    j+=1
  if b < a:
    c = 1
    j = 0
  if j>=30:
    break
```

Comment: ops, I removed my comment sorry- I didn't think you'd reply, it was "`j++` isn't valid syntax" just for future's sake.

Comment: how to show it is continually 0, like it could be  0,0,0,1,0, if I asked when exceed 4. I need it to stop when it does not change anymore, it is 1,0,1,0,0,0,0. Like this.

Comment: @XiaoyuHan that is why there is `j=0` after `c=1`. This will make the continuous counter 'j' 0 after it changes from that value.

Comment: I see...Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
misses=0
THRESHOLD = 30
for i in range(100):
    if b > a:
        misses += 1
        if misses >= THRESHOLD:
             break
        c= 0
    if b < a:
        misses = 0
        c = 1
```

Comment: How to stop when I need all the 0 stays together. I mean c is always the same, and the value of c is 0 for more than 30 times.

Comment: `misses` is increased from 0 to `THRESHOLD` for each successive `c=0` you have (note that what really matters is that `b > a`). As soon as misses reach 30, you break out of the loop.

Comment: Also, note that `misses` gets reset to 0 if `b < a`, so that you're effectively counting only the successive occurrences of `b > a`.

Comment: Got u! Thank you~~